# SSMS 2016 - custom sql code snippet folder vanishes after SSMS restart

Tags: ssms

I have created a few SQL code snippets, I have imported them to SSMS 2016 in the folder "My Code Snippets". This works fine.

Now I have organized the snippets into folders. I have then successfully added my folder tree to the Code Snippet Manager:
[image]

and it also is accessible on the Ctrl+K, Ctrl+X menu:

[image]

**However, as soon as I restart SSMS 2016 this folder is not listed there anymore.** (Neither in Code Snippet Manager, nor in the insert menu)

Whereas the snippets added to the My Code Snippets are still there, including the custom folder structure.

It is just a small inconvenience to go through the "My Code Snippets" folder everytime, but I wonder that everything works until a restart of the application.

P.S. Just as I was struggling with getting the code snippets running I want to share this info here. The code snippet manager will import also code snippets with wrong Type in the  tag. So the snippet gets then listed in the snippet manager but will not be listed in the Ctrl+K,Ctrl+X snipped menu. Took me quite a while to figure that out.

Answer (score 5):

I think this may be a known bug.

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32900221-ssms-2016-does-not-remember-added-sql-snippets-fol

Comment: With the connect site no longer active, this link is now dead.  Also not available on wayback machine nor Google Cache.

Comment: new link: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32900221-ssms-2016-does-not-remember-added-sql-snippets-fol

Comment: This bug is fixed in SSMS v18

Answer (score 1):

Here is the work around I am using.  It works quite well, but you do have to shuffle files around each time you install or upgrade SSMS.

Most of the "as installed" snippets are stored in this folder:  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\SQL\Snippets\1033.  The only snippets not in this folder are the "My Code Snippets", which is at C:\Users[UserName]\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Code Snippets\SQL\My Code Snippets.

Move all sub folders of C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\SQL\Snippets\1033 to a new sub folder.  You can call it "Microsoft" or "As Installed".

Restarting SSMS you will note that all those as installed snippets are now gone

With all the "as installed" snippets gone SSMS will now only show snippets from your My Code Snippets folder.  SSMS doesn't even show the normal "My Code Snippets" sub folder.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still struggling with this, someone with the tag Microsoft SQL Server (Product Manager, Microsoft Azure) posted on [feedback.azure.com](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32900221-ssms-2016-does-not-remember-added-sql-snippets-fol) on 6/5/2019 that this bug is fixed in SSMS 18. I don't have SSMS 18 yet, but I sure hope this is fixed as it has been a pain for a very long time.